# DbContext detect lazy loading

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, lazy-loading

I want to move to my entity framework code to .net standard 2.0, however I noticed lazy loading is not supported.

Is there anyway to detect when lazy loading is used in DbContext.  That way I can fix those calls before moving to .net standard.

Thanks

Steve

Comment: maybe it could helps you ? https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/lazy-loading

Comment: Entity Framework Core *does* support Lazy Loading, you are reading very old articles. To be honest, though, I'd never recommend using it

Comment: 95% plus of my code uses eager loading, but I don't know if there is the odd area of my code where lazy loading is used unintentionally.  So I would like to remove all lazy loaded code anyway.  Is there a way of detecting when DbContext uses lazy loading.

Comment: @Camilo Terevinto could you please expand on why you don't recommend using lazy loading? Personally, I use eager loading but I've been thinking of switching to lazy loading.

Comment: @PaoloGo Because of the "magic" that goes behind the curtain. You expect the framework to load the right entities at the right time and in an efficient way. You also perform multiple requests instead of one, just as you also need to keep the connection open for longer time. It's just too much magic for my taste

Comment: @stevec Not that I know of, I'd just turn off lazy loading and see what goes wrong (of course, not the best approach) assuming there isn't a set of tests in place

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're using EF 6 since you have not mentioned EF Core.

```
public class BloggingContext : DbContext
{
    public BloggingContext()
    {
        this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
    }
}
```

The above will disable lazy loading on your context. This might be a way forward. I am not suggesting putting this in place and deploying. I am suggesting putting this in place and testing.

Other than that perhaps checking for any "virtual" members on your context entities might help.

Also, as mentioned. Lazy loading IS now enabled in EF Core as of 2.1
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data#lazy-loading